# Make switch, case structure in assembly

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, msp430

How to make switch, case structure in assembler? What is right way or more corect?

This is my code in C, what I want to write in assembler.

```
if (diode_on == 1)
    {
        switch(diode_num)
            {
            case 0:
                //score += 3;
                break;

            case 1:
                //score += 3;                
                break;

            case 2:
                //score += 3;
                break;

            case 3:
                //score += 3;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        diode_on = 0;
    }
```

I need this for my project, MMSP430F5XX. The condition of the project is that one breaking routin is written in assembler. And this is code of breaking routin in C, what I try to write in assembler.

```
    #pragma vector=PORT2_VECTOR
__interrupt void port2handler(void)
{
    __delay_cycles(1000);

    if (diode_on == 1)
    {
        switch(diode_num)
            {
            case 0:
                if((P2IFG & BIT4)!=0)
                {
                    if ((P2IN & BIT4)==0)
                        //score += 3;
                        calculationScore(3);
                }
                else
                    //score--;
                    calculationScore(-1);
                break;

            case 1:
                if((P2IFG & BIT5)!=0)
                {
                    if ((P2IN & BIT5)==0)
                        //score += 3;
                        calculationScore(3);
                }
                else
                    //score--;
                    calculationScore(-1);
                break;

            case 2:
                if((P2IFG & BIT6)!=0)
                {
                    if ((P2IN & BIT6)==0)
                        //score += 3;
                        calculationScore(3);
                }
                else
                    //score--;
                    calculationScore(-1);
                break;

            case 3:
                if((P2IFG & BIT7)!=0)
                {
                    if ((P2IN & BIT7)==0)
                        //score += 3;
                        calculationScore(3);
                }
                else
                    //score--;
                    calculationScore(-1);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

        P4OUT &= ~(BIT3 | BIT4 | BIT5 | BIT6);          //gasimo diode
        diode_on = 0;
    }

    P2IFG &= ~(BIT4 | BIT5 | BIT6 | BIT7);              // brisanje flega
}
```

Comment: Switch with breaks is equivalent to if else

Comment: Can you tag an architecture, please? We can't answer without it.

Comment: we can answer without it just generically.  there are a number of other problems with the question beyond that that make it difficult to just give this person the answer to their homework question.

Comment: What have you done so far, post your attempt as part of the question.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I add architetcure. Its a MMSP430F5XX. I finish my project, write all in C, programing MMSP430F5XX. The condition of the project is that one breaking routin is written in assembler. For me routine for testers is most easy one, then other (timers...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you see when you compiled this? How did your compiler solve it?

Off the top of my head there are three simple ways to implement this but not all can be used.  First and foremost an if-then-else tree will always work, and depending on your case values is sometimes the only sane way to do it.

Everything else beyond that is "it depends" so say for example you took your comments out and you wanted 0,1,2,3 to add three to the score and all other values not...AND...diode_num could be any one of those numbers or some other value like 75. or even 4.  then you could/implement this as:

```
if(diode_num&3) goto skip;
score+=3;
skip:
```

of course in C (without the goto if you prefer) or in the syntax for your assembly language whatever target this is.

if the code you provided is such that diode_num can only be 0,1,2,3 then this is not dead code, but it optimizes down to score+=3 for all cases and the switch goes away.

assuming that is not the case another "it depends" is a jump table which not only depends on your case values but also depends on the instruction set and depends on all the possible values that can come in, say for example outside the code you have provided and assuming you actually did something for each case as the code you have provided is mostly dead code it becomes

```
if(diode_on == 1) diode_on = 0;
```

you should have provided a better example.  but if the compiler and optimizer can see code you have not provided and lets say finds that the possible range of values for diode_num is 0-7 and you want to do something special for each of 0,1,2,3 and a jump table is possible in this instruction set you have not specified, then

```
load some_register,table_base_add
shift_left temp_register,diode_num,2 ;assuming 32 bit addresses
add some_register,temp_register
load another_register,[some_register]
branch_to another_register

table_base_add: .word table_base
.align
;jump table
table_base:
.word case0
.word case1
.word case2
.word case3
.word switch_end
.word switch_end
.word switch_end
.word switch_end

;case 0 code
case0:
do something
b switch_end
;case 1 code
case1:
do something
b switch_end
;case 2 code
case2:
do something
b switch_end
;case 3 code
case3:
do something
b switch_end
switch_end:
code after switch
```

if the compiler cannot determine the range of input values it may or may not choose to try a jump table.

you can make it even more optimized, lets say the range of diode_num was strictly 0,1,2,3 and you wanted to do something different for each case but it was very simple and in this case I am using fixed sized instructions for this further optimization.

```
load some_register,base_add
shift_left temp_register,diode_num,4
add some_register,temp_register
branch_to some_register

base_add: .word base
base:
    ;case 0 code
    one instruction
    b switch_end
    nop
    nop
    ;case 1 code
    one instruction
    one instruction
    one instruction
    b switch_end
    ;case 2 code
    one instruction
    one instruction
    b switch_end
    nop
    ;case 3 code
    one instruction
    nop
    nop
    b switch_end
    switch_end:
```

in this case assuming 16 bytes (four 32 bit words) per case you could just add or or the case times 16 to the base address and jump there, no jump table required just math.  if the cases were 1,2,3,4 you could subtract one then multiply by 16 (shift left 4) then add to base and jump there.

Since you are the optimizing compiler then you can always use an if then else tree to implement this, or if you know more about the specifics of the range of inputs, the number of cases, amount of code per case (which is the first thing you should code and build the skeleton around it) and instruction set then you can maybe optimize.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll be in the lab and test this approach. I write you, how it was.. :)